# ignore column width in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm getting the follow

```
SQLPLUS> create table source(aa nvarchar2(2), bb nvarchar2(100), cc nvarchar2(10));
insert into source values ('aa',null,'aa');
insert into source values (null,'aa','aa');
insert into source values ('aa','aaa',null);
set serveroutput on pages 0 feedback off echo off head off verify off numformat 99999999999.9999999999999 null '\N' colsep '  ' linesize 32767
select * from source;

aa  \N                                                    aa
\N  aa                                                    aa
aa  aaa                                                   \N
```

I want to ignore the column width and show the result as `<value><colsep><value>` without touching the SQL (only the commands before it or `sqlplus`). So the result will look like:

```
aa  \N  aa
\N  aa  aa
aa  aaa  \N
```

(representing tab as two spaces)

Comment: What version of Oracle and sqlplus are you using?

Comment: version `21.0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`CASE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96) and concatenation [`||`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Concatenation-Operator.html#GUID-08C10738-706B-4290-B7CD-C279EBC90F7E) in one statement.

```
select 
  (CASE WHEN AA IS NULL THEN N'\N' ELSE AA END)
  || CHR(9) || 
  (CASE WHEN BB IS NULL THEN N'\N' ELSE BB END)
  || CHR(9) || 
  (CASE WHEN CC IS NULL THEN N'\N' ELSE CC END)
  ResultSet 
  FROM source;
```

This returns:

| RESULTSET |
| --- |
| aa \N aa |
| \N aa aa |
| aa aaa \N |

The [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mF7hQQZp) link displays the working code using your example data.

Comment: I should have said, I can't touch the SQL itself, only what comes before like `set` or `sqlplus`

Answer (score 0):

Try "set markup csv on":

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect user/pass/@db
set markup csv on
select * from source
/
```