# How do I set tab as a delimiter in sqlplus markup

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to return `sqlplus` output as tsv. For that I use `set markup csv`. but it does not accept tab as delimiter, not `\t` and not actual tab.

error is

```
SP2-1660: Invalid option. Only a single character be specified.
```

on either of:

```
sqlplus -M "CSV on delimiter '\t' QUOTE OFF" -s user/pass@host
sqlplus -M "CSV on delimiter '    ' QUOTE OFF" -s user/pass@host
```

`sqlplus` version is `21.0`.
The solution has to be `sqlplus` argument or `set` command.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106323/sqlplus-settings-to-generate-tab-separated-data-file) help?

Comment: In order to get to the bottom of your issues regarding your question [ignore column width in sqlplus](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/324682/15356) and this question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/324770/15356) , could you possibly write a single question containing all the requirements and details in one question? Otherwise we'll be going round and round in circles trying to provide you with an adequate solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution has to be sqlplus argument or set command.

Why? `sqlplus` can run a script automatically upon login that can set the formatting you need. Just an example:

```
$ cat $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql
col TAB# new_value TAB NOPRINT
select chr(9) TAB# from dual;
set markup csv on delimiter "&TAB" quote off
set heading off termout off echo off

$ cat 1.sql
spool out.txt
select owner, object_name, object_type from dba_objects fetch first 5 rows only;
exit

$ sqlplus -S bp/bp @1.sql




$ cat out.txt
SYS     OBJ$    TABLE
SYS     CCOL$   TABLE
SYS     CLU$    TABLE
SYS     SEG$    TABLE
SYS     I_OBJ3  INDEX

$ sed 's/\t/thisisatab/g' out.txt
SYSthisisatabOBJ$thisisatabTABLE
SYSthisisatabCCOL$thisisatabTABLE
SYSthisisatabCLU$thisisatabTABLE
SYSthisisatabSEG$thisisatabTABLE
SYSthisisatabI_OBJ3thisisatabINDEX

$
```

TSV is just 1 `sed` away from CSV anyway.

Comment: Love it! Is there a way to use this specific `glogin.sql` only when I specify? (as I would want regular sqlplus connection to return as non tsv)

Comment: `login.sql` + `ORACLE_PATH` is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the `-M "CSV ON DELIMI '\t' QUOTE OFF"` parameters when starting sqlplus turns off certain `SET` options as outlined in the following article:

> When SET MARKUP CSV is enabled, the following SET commands will have no effect on the output:
>
> - SET COLSEP
> - SET HEADSEP
> - SET LINESIZE
> - SET NEWPAGE
> - SET PAGESIZE
> - SET PAUSE
> - SET RECSEP
> - SET SHIFTINOUT
> - SET TAB
> - SET TRIMOUT
> - SET TRIMSPOOL
> - SET UNDERLINE
> - SET WRAP

<sup>***Reference:** [Unsupported Commands when SET MARKUP CSV is Enabled](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-0AA910C4-C22A-4A9E-BE13-AAA059CC7919) (Oracle Docs | User's Guide and Reference)*</sup>

And because the `DELIMI[TER]` part of the startup parameter is very limited, you might want to forgo the `-M CSV` startup parameter and instead opt for the `SET COLSEP` setting.

```
SQL> set colsep '       '
SQL> select DUMMY, DUMMY from dual;

D       D
-       -
X       X

SQL>
```

Good luck.

Comment: using `set colsep` brings me back to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/324682/ignore-column-width-in-sqlplus?noredirect=1#comment633334_324682

Comment: You wrote: _The solution has to be sqlplus argument or set command._

Comment: What I meant was that while `colsep` helps, it does not provide valid tsv as it outputs the full column's length. so if the column length is 4 and the value is `a` - I get `a    `. and obviously `a` != `a    `.